Ubuntu 22.04 on Zephyrus G16 2024 : blinking black cursor on boot after installing NVIDIA drivers
I have the 2024 version of the ASUS ROG Zephyrus G16 with an NVIDIA RTX 4070 GPU. Ubuntu 22.04 works fine until I install NVIDIA drivers, and once I install the drivers, upon restart, I see the boot log and then it just hangs at a blinking cursor, the login screen never shows up.
I can get into tty mode by pressing Ctrl+alt+F2, and I can log in. If I run nvidia-smi after doing that, I do see the NVIDIA GPU so the driver itself is working fine. For some reason, the X server (Wayland?) does not show up.
I tried several different methods of installing the drivers (Additional Drivers from within Ubuntu, the graphics-drivers ppa, as well as the run file downloaded from NVIDIA directly), and they all result in the same issue. How can I fix this?

Did you turn off secure boot, or install your MOK key at a prompt when installing the drivers?
